# Upload Images (Express/Node/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, image-upload

I'm looking for the best approach to build an upload functionality for a kind of web gallery application.

I've found several approaches from saving image data to Mongo:

https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370

to save them locally on the server:

https://www.terlici.com/2015/05/16/uploading-files-locally.html

I guess there is no general answer on how to implement this functionality.
My scenario is like following:

I'm using MongoDB, NodeJS and Express on top of it (so far).
One user is handling the content (creating blog posts and adding images to a gallery).

Images are from a few kB's too several mb's.

What's the best way to implement a functionality for this usecase?

Option #1: Store the image data locally on the server and their metadata into MongoDB?

Option #2: Store the image data and metadata directly to MongoDB?

Option #3: I'm open for any hints and tips!

I'm very new to web development, I appreciate any help, package names, coding paradigma idea's... whatever is going to help me to write a good web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting image data to base64 format and transmit to node server.

Or you can take a look at [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that.